# how to overwrite the each parameters value if it is invalid in dialogflow webhook integration code

Tags: dialogflow-es

I had created one intent with six parameters. I need to validate each one. So i enabled webhook for slot filling. But i have a problem here. When one input is invalid, I am not able to get that one again. How can I overwrite the parameter values if it is invalid?

I'm using python code for entire webservice integration and validation.

May I get any sample lines of code in python

Answer (score 0):

Slot-filling with the webhook isn't for validation purposes. It is for creating more dynamic prompts when the user hasn't provided a required parameter.

Comment: how to do that? i have read that slot filling is called only when the parameter is filled up. it can be used to fill other slots or to perform validation once the parameter is provided.

Comment: How to do what?

Comment: how to create dynamic prompts when the user hasn't provided required parameter using `webhook for slot-filling`?

Comment: @sid8491 - That sounds like a different question than the original poster's question. I'd suggest you ask it as a new Stack Overflow question and indicate what you've tried and what problems you're having.

Comment: sure i'll do that :)